# How to get only one latest record using Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I have about 7 records in which two records with same user but with different MailLevel & SentDate Status, so i would like to get only one latest record of that particular user. could any one help me how to perform the Sql Query

Please find the image below for clear understanding

http://s16.postimg.org/res5p5gmd/TESTPAGE.png
[image: My test page]

Comment: I can't see your picture, please include all relevant information in the question.

Comment: please find the below image url https://s3.amazonaws.com/TestImageUpload/TESTPAGE.PNG

Comment: Like that but even better, actually copy the information into text in the question.

Comment: are u able to look at the image ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

as per my understanding for a user record having 2 times entry with different maillevel and sent date it will pick the recent record along with other records.

```
  select *
  from
   (
     SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [creatorName] ORDER BY [SendDate] DESC)
     AS [RowNum],     
     *
     FROM [YourTable]
   )base
  WHERE [RowNum] = 1
```

Comment: perfect!! i need that along with other records, could you help me in this query and WHERE [RowNum] = 1 dosent work

Comment: Hey Got it , the got the result for the given above query

Comment: can you send me the table script or error message so that i can send you the solution. As per my knowledge the above code will work with all records.

Comment: You just copied my answer

Comment: As did you with mine haha.

Comment: I have call the row number in the object and then filter the recodrs not directly in the select code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the latest record of this one specific user you can use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectLatestRecored

@UserId int

AS

SELECT TOP 1 [Col1], [Col2] ,[Col3], [SendDate], [MailLevel]
FROM [YourTable]
ORDER BY [SentDate] DESC 
WHERE [UserId] = @UserId

GO
```

If you want the latest record of each user :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectLatestRecoreds

AS

SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UserId] ORDER BY [SendDate] DESC) AS [RowNum],     
  [Col1], [Col2] ,[Col3], [SendDate], [MailLevel]

FROM [YourTable]
WHERE [RowNum] = 1

GO
```

Comment: well there are no input parameters for My SP, its admin panel where i need all the users list . in the given image a user record 2 times with different MailLevel and SentDate but i need only one recent Record Via Date which is MailLevel 2

Comment: the syntax in both of your queries is invalid

Comment: Hi Again, am using Temp table find the query below i have written                              SELECT TOP 1  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID, ORDER BY SentDate DESC) AS MailLevelStatus,     
 CreatorName,
 PhoneNumber,
 EmailId,
 ProjectName,
 StageName
 FROM #GetDraftProjectForMailing
 
 ORDER BY SentDate DESC WHERE  MailLevelStatus=1

Comment: It does work, you put a redundant  comma after "PARTITION BY ProjectID," so its not compiling, and added a redundant TOP,  and a redundant order by

Comment: The code should look like this: SELECT

 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID ORDER BY SentDate DESC) AS MailLevelStatus,
 CreatorName, PhoneNumber, EmailId, ProjectName, StageName 

 FROM #GetDraftProjectForMailing 

 WHERE MailLevelStatus = 1

Comment: @Guy Levin. You can't use RowNum in your where because as its an alias. You have to first sub select it.

Answer (score 1):

Sub select the table adding a row number column and where clause on the main select

```
SELECT *  
FROM (
    SELECT MyTable.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY UserId ORDER BY MailLevel DESC, SentDate DESC) AS R 
    FROM MyTable ) AS T 
WHERE T.R=1
```